# On the Lebesgue measure a basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

It's quite common to ask the size of a set in terms of its cardinality. In the case of the vector space $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, to ask for the [cardinality of a basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6244/is-there-a-quick-proof-as-to-why-the-vector-space-of-mathbbr-over-mathbb/3530396#3530396) or even [to give it a subset of it in which it is countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2294486/consider-the-vector-space-mathbb-r-over-the-field-mathbb-q). In my sense, I am curious to know how common a vector $\boldsymbol{v} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ has coordinates that "randomly fall" in a linearly independent set of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Hence, this question can be thought of as:

> What is the largest Lebesgue measure a basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

If a basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has a positive measure, it's reasonable to say that it's "common" to have a $\boldsymbol{v} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ that "randomly fall" in a linearly independent set of vectors.

Comment: I guess the inner measure of a Hamel basis is necessarily zero; but a basis could be constructed with full outer measure.

Comment: You can put a link to the result where such a guess may be observed. For me, it's quite counter-intuitive that such a Hamel basis does not have full measure.